# How to show that $f_{0}f_{1}+f_{1}f_{2}+...+f_{2n-1}f_{2n} = f^{2}_{2n}$

Tags: induction

The following problem:

The Fibonacci number is denoted by  $f_{n}$, **show that** the following holds when $n$ is a positive integer:

$f_{0}f_{1}+f_{1}f_{2}+...+f_{2n-1}f_{2n} = f^{2}_{2n}$

My idea was to do an induction proof, which holds for $n$ = 1

$f_{0}f_{1} + f_{1}f_{2} = f^{2}_{2}$

So we assume it holds for $n$ and show for $n+1$

$f_{0}f_{1}+f_{1}f_{2}+...+f_{2n-1}f_{2n} + f_{2n}f_{2n+1} = f^{2}_{2n} + f_{2n}f_{2n+1}$

I fail to get  $f^{2}_{2n+1}$ out of the term  $f^{2}_{2n} + f_{2n}f_{2n+1}$

Is there a difference between "show that" and "prove that". So might be induction the wrong tool here?

Many thanks for your hints in advance :-)

Comment: There is no differeence between "show that" and "prove that" and induction is probably the right tool. However you have a small error. The sum has $2n$ terms. So when you increase $n$ by one you should have 2 leftover terms. not just one.

Comment: which means I have to add  $f_{2n}f_{2n+1}+f_{2n+1}f_{2n+2}$ to both sides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following step has a mistake as Jorik has mentioned.

> So we assume it holds for $n$ and show for $n+1$
>
> $$f_{0}f_{1}+f_{1}f_{2}+...+f_{2n-1}f_{2n} + f_{2n}f_{2n+1} = f^{2}_{2n} + f_{2n}f_{2n+1}$$

Rather it should be as follows:

$$f_{0}f_{1}+f_{1}f_{2}+...+f_{2n-1}f_{2n} + f_{2n}f_{2n+1} + f_{2n+1}f_{2n+2}$$
$$= f^{2}_{2n} + f_{2n}f_{2n+1} + f_{2n+1}f_{2n+2}$$
$$= f^{2}_{2n} + f_{2n}f_{2n+1} + f_{2n+1}(f_{2n+1}+f_{2n})$$ using the property of Fibonacci numbers
$$= f^{2}_{2n} + 2f_{2n}f_{2n+1} + f^{2}_{2n+1}$$
$$= (f_{2n}+f_{2n+1})^2$$
$$= f^{2}_{2n+2}$$
$$= f^{2}_{2(n+1)}$$

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah man, thanks! Math is fun!

Comment: You're welcome. If you like my answer, you can accept it by clicking the tick mark beside my answer.